# After enabling Proguard with Twilio Programmable Chat chatting module not working

Tags: android, twilio, proguard

I have enabled proguard for release flavor but after that Twilio  Programmable Chat stoped Working.

I have added this https://github.com/twilio/twilio-chat-demo-android/blob/master/chat-demo-android/proguard-project.txt in Proguard file.

```
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}
```

build.gradle

```
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try adding rules from this file: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-chat-demo-android/blob/master/chat-demo-android/proguard-rules.pro

Comment: Tried this Not working as well

Comment: Try enabling the Proguard for Debug build and Check the Logs .. Then if you find any Error the check class Mapping file..

Answer (score 0):

Try this, [proguard-rules.pro](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-chat-demo-android/blob/master/chat-demo-android/proguard-rules.pro)

```
#==============================================
# Proguard rules for use with IP Messaging SDK
#==============================================

-keep class com.twilio.chat.** { *; }
-keepattributes InnerClasses
#-keep interface com.twilio.chat.** { *; }
#-keep enum com.twilio.chat.** { *; }

## Keep native methods

-keepclasseswithmembernames class com.twilio.chat.** {
    native <methods>;
}

## Keep callbacks from native
# ?

#======================================
# Local demo application configuration
#======================================

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

## EasyAdapter

-dontwarn uk.co.ribot.easyadapter.**
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepclassmembers class * extends uk.co.ribot.easyadapter.ItemViewHolder {
    public <init>(...);
}

## Google libraries

-dontwarn android.support.**
-keep class com.google.ads.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.firebase.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
```